# To check for same ids while setting row values as column values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written a mysql query to get a row out of multiple rows and columns values are diffents row values. Eg. of my table data is as follows:

```
inquiry_id mailer_id    sent_on         edition  event_id  Event_name
 28           1        2015-01-14        abc        1       aaa
 28           2        2015-01-12        edf        1       aaa
 28           1        2015-01-15        pqr        2       bbb
 28           3        2015-01-17        xyz        2       bbb
```

I have written a query to get the result as follows:

```
     SELECT inquiry_id, event_name,MAX(ValueData1) as ValueData1 ,MAX(ValueData2) as ValueData2
      ,MAX(ValueData3) as ValueData3
     ,MAX(ValueData4) as ValueData4
    FROM
    (
      SELECT  inquiry_id,event_id,event_name
      ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 1 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData1
      ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 2 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData2
      ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 3 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData3
     ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 4 THEN  CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on)  END AS ValueData4

      FROM crm_support_inquiry 

) AS crm_support_inquiry
GROUP BY inquiry_id,event_id,event_name
```

And the output is as follows:

```
inquiry_id Event_name valueData1        valueData2     valueData3 valueData4
    28      aaa        abc-2015-01-14    edf-2015-01-12    null     null
    28      bbb        pqr-2015-01-15      null        xyz-2015-01-17  null
```

This is right and as required. But how this query can be edited to handle the same mailer_id and concanate the data in the existing column.
Sample of what i want is as follows:
If suppose i have same two mailers for one event:

```
inquiry_id mailer_id    sent_on         edition  event_id  Event_name
 28           1        2015-01-14        abc        1       aaa
 28           2        2015-01-12        edf        1       aaa
 28           1        2015-01-15        pqr        2       bbb
 28           3        2015-01-17        xyz        2       bbb
 28           3        2015-01-12        hdh        2       bbb
```

the output must be as follows:

```
 inquiry_id Event_name valueData1        valueData2     valueData3 valueData4
    28      aaa        abc-2015-01-14    edf-2015-01-12    null     null
    28      bbb        pqr-2015-01-15      null        xyz-2015-01-17/hdh-2015-01-12  null
```

The data with same mailer id should be concanated as that value in same valuedata column.How this should be handled in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you need to change this:

```
MAX(ValueData1) as ValueData1
```

to this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(ValueData1 SEPARATOR '/') as ValueData1
```

(and similarly for the other fields). Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b263/3.

See [the documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`, under §12.18.1 "GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions" in the *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: @user3300727: I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, you can see at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b263/3 that my answer works fine based on the information in your question, so if "its not helping" you, then you'll need to put in some effort to figure out why. Good luck with it!

Comment: Actually i was getting the output as BLOB so i was not able to decide whether it is right or no.